# Disable confirmation emails in Thunderbird Lightning Calendar

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, lightning

How do I make [Thunderbird Lightning Calendar](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/calendar/) stop sending confirmation emails?

There is a [closed bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=447674) on Bugzilla, but I cannot find an option to disable confirmation emails.